# In iOS7, abnormal popping action of UINavigationController with edge swiping

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I found one that looks like iOS7 bug while popping view controllers(VCs) in UINavigationController with edge swiping.

I set up as following VC hierarchy:

```
UINagivationController
  |
  --- UIVewControllerR (root)
            |
            --- UIViewControllerA
                      |
                      --- UIViewControllerB
```

I tried to pop UIViewControllerB up by edge swiping and popped UIViewControllerA up continuously. It worked well. But, If first swiping action is canceled then retry to pop it up, a bug I found comes out. After popping UIViewControllerA, I found that UIViewControllerA's navigation bar items were still showed despite popping UIViewControllerA up.

In short, UIViewControllerR was showed with items of UIViewControllerA's navigation bar items.

There is no code that is likely to affect transition of UINavigationController.
Is it a bug on iOS7?

Comment: So, you start to swipe B, then cancel.  Then go back to A, then back to R, and when you get back to R, the nav bar still show's A's stuff?

Comment: @nhgrif Yes. going back with not back button but edge swiping.

Comment: But the order I listed was the exact order?  Can you put a sample project together that replicates this bug an post it on github along with exact instructions for replicating the problem?

Comment: @nhgrif I discovered that I wrote the question exactly. sorry for my miss question. I will revise it soon.

Comment: i am facing the exact same problem.Did you manage to find a solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

What I did was in my UINagivationController class, set a BOOL property called

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL interactivePopGestureComplete;
```

and then in init of that UINagivationController

```
self.interactivePopGestureComplete = YES;
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
        [self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(defaultGestureAction:)];
```

and the action method like this:

```
- (void)defaultGestureAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        self.interactivePopGestureComplete = NO;
    else
        self.interactivePopGestureComplete = YES;
}
```

and in viewWillAppear: or viewWillLayoutSubviews: (in the viewControllers where there is this problem), wherever in these two methods you are updating the navigationBarButtons and the navigationBar, just check if

```
// Lets say our UINagivationController class name is NavigationCon
NavigationCon *navCon = (NavigationCon *)self.navigationController;
if(navCon.interactivePopGestureComplete)
{
    // only then update navigationBar
}
```

Comment: Sorry for giving feedback lately. I tested your suggestion to my code that has the problem. Your code really worked well except one part. viewWillAppear: and viewWillLayoutSubviews: is called when interactionGestureRecognizer just starts to work so that two functions are not called at the end of recognizing. For working around, I overrided viewDidAppear: with same codes that you suggested me to place in viewWillAppear:. I really appreciate you to find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the problem your facing

There are two scenario's it can happen.

1.Where have you done Navigation Bar text changes in all controller.If you have done in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear then this might happen..You will have to do it in viewDidLoad

2.Doing changes on the navigationbar before the transition changes end.

Tell me if it helps you.